# Pureftpd can't list directories with big number of files

Tags: linux, pure-ftpd

Pureftpd is running as:

`/usr/sbin/pure-ftpd-mysql-virtualchroot -l mysql:/etc/pure-ftpd/db/mysql.conf -l pam -P 1.2.3.4 -u 1000 -O clf:/var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log -Y 1 -E -D -8 UTF-8 -L 1000000:15 -p 31000:31059 -J HIGH -A -H -b -d -B`

`LimitRecursion` is set to 1 000 000 files and 15 subdirs as you can see `-L 1000000:15`. Pureftpd restarted several times.

**I can list directories which have 7k, 12k files, but directory which have ~500k files wont list.**

`filezilla` and `lftp` gives same error when connected remotely, but error is same even when connected locally on problematic server (with `lftp`):

```
...
---- Got EOF on data connection                                 
---- Closing data socket
<--- 226-Sorry, we were unable to read [/web/wp-content/uploads/2021/02]
<--- 226-Options: -a -l 
<--- 226 0 matches total
```

Permissions of /web/wp-content/uploads/2021/02 was triple checked.

Are there any rlimits, or any other server related limits to be checked? One thing that comes to mind is limits for user that is logged as pureftp user.

Any help regarding problem would be wonderful.